# WPF ComboBox display selected value?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Before displaying the UI, data will be retrieved from database and these data to be displayed on screen.

Now I have a screen with 2 fields. One `textbox` and one `combobox`.

Value of `textbox` being bind as below:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding [someViewModel].person.name, Mode=TwoWay, 
ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True,
ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
```

Now I have a ComboBox that get the list of value from database, says **Yellow, Green, Blue**
Below is the way I bind `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
ItemSource="{Binding [someViewModel].ColorList}" 
DisplayMemberPath="ColorName" SelectedValuePath="ColorID" 
SelectedValue="{Binding [someViewModel].person.ColorID}"
```

My problem now is when I load the page, the default selected value will be based on `[someViewModel].person.ColorID` but it's showing empty instead. There are values in the ComboBox. When I debug it, there are value in `[someViewModel].person.ColorID` but it just wouldn't show?

When I change the value from **Yellow** to **Green**, the value will be reflected to `[someViewModel].person.ColorID` as well which fits what I need

Comment: The first part (TextBox) of your question is unrelated to the problem and just makes your question longer to read and understand.

Comment: It's just to elaborate more to show the structure of the object

Comment: Does any item in [someViewModel].ColorList has  ColorID value equal to  [someViewModel].person.Color ?

Comment: Is the problem just that when the page loads no value is selected in the ComboBox? Everything works correctly afterwards? 
If so, have you tried, setting the initial value for the ComboBox programatically?

Comment: Remove the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" attribute. While there's not enough information to diagnose the issue fully, you're probably binding multiple combo boxes with the same collection, which by setting this property will lead to the issue you're experiencing. You shouldn't need this feature given the example you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Has your Color class ColorID property, or just Id?

If so:
`SelectedValuePath="Id"`